# Postgres Connector Class using Pandas read sql query

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, class

I want to create a small connector class that connects to a postgres DB, reads in a file that contains some sql code and returns the results in a Panda's DataFrame

```
sql_file = open('sql/xxxxxxxxx.sql','r')

class MyDatabase():

    def __init__(self, db="xxx", user="xxx", host='xxx', port=5432, pwd='xxx'):

        self.conn = psy.connect(database=db, user=user, host=host, port=port, password=pwd)



def query(self, query_file):

    pd.read_sql_query(query_file.read(), self.conn)



def close(self):

    self.conn.close()



db = MyDatabase()

data = db.query(sql_file)

print(data)

db.close()
```

My SQL code works well outside the class apporach, if I run this code this line

```
data = db.query(sql_file)
```

never finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are attempting to read the results of a query and store the same as a pandas dataframe.

You could try using sqlalchemy as below (replace with the relevant credentials for your database). The *SELECT * FROM table limit 1* below is a sample query, but you can replace this with the relevant query for your situation.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost/tablename')
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table limit 1", engine)
```